# Sphinx weird behavior

Tags: sphinx

I have weird trouble creating index on sphinx 2.0.5-id64-release (r3308)

/etc/sphinx/sphinx.conf

```
source keywords
{
        // ..
    sql_query       = \
        SELECT keywords.lid, keywords.keyword FROM keywords_sites \
        LEFT JOIN keywords ON keywords_sites.kid = keywords.kid \
        GROUP BY keywords_sites.kid \

    sql_attr_uint       = lid
    sql_field_string    = keyword
        // ...

}
```

I get warning

```
WARNING: attribute 'lid' not found - IGNORING
```

But when i change query to:

```
sql_query       = \
    SELECT 1, keywords.lid, keywords.keyword FROM keywords_sites \
    LEFT JOIN keywords ON keywords_sites.kid = keywords.kid \
    GROUP BY keywords_sites.kid \
```

I don't get any warnings. Why is this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first column from the sql_query is ALWAYS used as the document_id.

The document_id can not be defined as an attibute.

If you want to store the primary key in an attribute as well, then you need to include it twice in the query.